# Using Raspberry Pi Zero W, rugged case is necessary for full time work?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have no experience with Raspberry Pi Boards ever.

For building a solution, operative 18 hours a day.

May I need to include a rugged case or some rugged version of RPI Zero?

Comment: why do you think that you need a rugged case? .... read what you wrote ... do you see anything that indicates what you are planning to build?

Comment: D'you have a hostile environment, or is your Pi sitting gently on an air conditioned desktop.  I have two Pi 3s that run 24x7x366 (Hey! It's a leap year.)  One of them has a heat sink, but it doesn't really seem necessary.

Comment: Bob Brown  in most cases  air conditioned, in the ceiling.